Make cURL resume interrupted downloads using the 'until' loop
Here is a solution how to make cURL automatically resume interrupted downloads, from the 2013 blog post by Juan Nunez-Iglesias:
export ec=18; while [ $ec -eq 18 ]; do curl -O -C - http://site.xyz/file.zip; export ec=$?; done

It has been posted several times here and on Stack Overflow, both the original version and with slight changes inside the while loop.
The changes inside the while loop were introduced by different people to make the script more robust.

"The exit code curl chucks when a download is interrupted is 18, and $? gives you the exit code of the last command in bash. So, while the exit code is 18, keep trying to download the file, maintaining the filename (-O) and resuming where the previous download left off (-C)." - Juan Nunez-Iglesias
"As Jan points out in the comments, depending what is going wrong with the download, your error code may be different. Just change 18 to whatever error you're seeing to get it to work for you! (If you're feeling adventurous, you could change the condition to while [ $ec -ne 0 ], but that feels like using a bare except in Python, which is bad. ;)" - Juan Nunez-Iglesias
"In my case curl exits with different codes, so I check for success code instead: while [ $ec -ni 0 ]" - Ilya Belsky, here

In March, Helder Magalhães suggested to replace the while loop in the original Juan's version with until:

This solution can be further simplified using until unstead. See related thread.

Though I'm not really good in using cURL or in shell scripting, I would try to write it myself, but the problem to write it myself is not the script itself but the lack of understanding how to properly test it.
Could somebody show how to implement Helder's idea? And does it really make script more robust?
I use Zsh.

You don't really need all the exporting and checking.  You could just use:
while ! curl -O -C - http://site.xyz/file.zip; do echo "Retrying..."; done


Some context that may help.
Your original code, if curl fails, it will return 18, and will continually loop until it doesn't equal 18.
The above solution, it's essentially looping until it succeeds instead of monitoring it's failure.  In order to make using exit codes more feasible, you need a more complex program in mind. Because, even with the while !, you can easily use && and || for the next success or failure conditional.
For example:
while ! curl -O -C - http://site.xyz/file.zip; do echo "Retrying..."; done || { echo "Failure."; exit 1; }; echo "Success."

is the exact same thing as:
#!/bin/bash

export ec=18

while [ $ec -eq 18 ]; 
    do curl -O -C - http://site.xyz/file.zip
    export ec=$?
    echo "Retrying..."
done

# If this loop completes, the return code will be 0.

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Failure!"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Success."

exit 0

It requires more complexity to make use of assigning variables and checking exit codes, or it's really just overkill.

Note that while ! is until (as in the OP's question). Actually, historically, the Bourne shell (where that syntax came from) had until but not !.

@StéphaneChazelas Ahh.  That would explain why I've never used until.  But, really, I was.  Interesting.

Thanks, Jay! But what might be a reason that guy used all that exporting and checking? Maybe there are some special cases?

@jsx97 Certainly.  If you wanted to do an additional task, for instance.  As soon as the command returns 0 instead of 18, you could run additional commands.  There's a number of possibilities that would make it useful.
